# modules::run returning a NULL result

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I have a controller that lists some offers I created.
Foreach offer, I want to display the number of unread messages associated.

I thought using modules::run but when I call :

```
<?php echo Modules::run('messages/messages/get_number_new_messages/'.$oOffer->offer_id); ?>
```

Nothing is displayed. If I call the get_number_new_messages directly in my url, it returns me the int I want (ie: "1")

Here is my messages controller function :

```
public function get_number_new_messages($bForOffers = false){
        $iNumberMessages = $this->messages_model->count_new_messages($this->current_user->previous_last_login, $bForOffers);

        $aDatas = array();
        $aDatas['iNumberMessages'] = $iNumberMessages;

        return $this->load->view('messages/get_number_new_messages', $aDatas);
    }
```

I also call

```
<?php echo Modules::run('messages/messages/get_number_new_messages/a'); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo Modules::run('messages/messages/get_number_new_messages'); ?>
```

in one of my theme file

Am I missing something... ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the third parameter on loading a view must be set to true in order to return your view as a string.

In your get_number_new_messages method you will need to do this:

```
return $this->load->view('messages/get_number_new_messages', $aDatas,true);
```

...or this (calling view will output it directly; you don't need to use return):

```
$this->load->view('messages/get_number_new_messages', $aDatas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it...

It was :

```
<?php echo Modules::run('messages/messages/get_number_new_messages', $oOffer->offer_id); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo Modules::run('messages/messages/get_number_new_messages/'.$oOffer->offer_id); ?>
```